# How do you copy un-neighboring lines in VI?

Tags: vim, editor, vi

In the below example, i want to copy lines 1,2,4 and 5 (without line 3):

```
var copyMe=true;
var copyMeAsWell=true;
var doNotCopyMe = 123;
var copyMeWithLine1And2And5=true;
var alsoCopyMe=True;
```

So when i paste the yanked lines i will get:

```
var copyMe=true;
var copyMeAsWell=true;
var copyMeWithLine1And2And5=true;
var alsoCopyMe=True;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
:1,2yank q
:4,5yank Q
```

to put the content into register `q` (the uppercase `Q` means 'append to register q').
You can then paste it with `"qp` (or simply `p` if you didn't alter the unnamed register in between).

Note: `:yank` can be shortened to `:y`

---

If you'd rather yank from normal mode you can also use `"qy` and `"Qy`.

Comment: I just checked and it worked, even though it is not THAT fast to use .. is there a way to visually select lines 1,2,4,5 and then use yank to copy them ? (maybe it should be a different question) ..

Comment: One way to do it is with the [multiselect](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953) plugin. Note that it hasn't been updated in a while; either it's good enough, or the developer has given up.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do this with command, you can do:

```
:3d|1,4y|u
```

In fact, it means, remove #3 line, copy those lines you want, then undo.